# Is it possible to install an application made to run on Azure Cloud Services (classic) run on a standalone Windows VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

Looking to run what we are currently running on Azure Cloud Services worker instance on a standalone Windows Server Virtual Machine.

Due to autoscaling limitations with Cloud Services (specifically around instance protection), we are looking to replicate the setup in this other fashion.

Is this possible?

What would it require?

Not sure what pre-reqs may be needed to recreate the Cloud Services Windows instance.

Obviously have all of the resources needed to create the CSPKG & CSCFG files, but cannot figure out how they are processed and deployed on the Cloud Services Worker instance.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you check Virtual machine scalesets as it serves the autoscale purpose . you can refer this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview

Comment: VMSS is the target.  The issue is being able to install the same application/service on VMSS/standalone Virtual Machine as we do Cloud Services.   Deployment to cloud services requires two files, a CSPKG file and CSCFG file.

Comment: Ok if you want VMSS and deploy your own service or application to it then please refer azure app services (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview#:~:text=Azure%20App%20Service%20is%20an%20HTTP-based%20service%20for,with%20ease%20on%20both%20Windows%20and%20Linux-based%20environments.) please refer this https://stackify.com/comparison-azure-app-services-vs-cloud-services/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a great way to achieve this without some dedicated development work. I'm not aware of any way to run azure web/worker-role compatible packages outside existing azure offerings. :(

That said, a well-factored application ought to limit the scope of necessary work. :)

The fundamental challenge I see here is that the CSPKG/CSCFG service is running in an opinionated application model: OnStart(), OnStop(), various environment values and configuration management are all supplied by the application model. This is Platform as a Service (PaaS).

VMSS, on the other hand, has no opinions about your application model. You can do whatever you like to start up, shut down, manage configuration, and so forth. This is Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS).

If you're looking at moving from a PaaS model to an IaaS model, you'll have to pick up any work that the platform was doing for you, so you'll have to define your configuration mechanisms, your startup and shutdown hooks, etc. This is very achievable and there are about a million (give or take) tools out there to help with all this work, but it's nonetheless work that will have to be done. The more your service relies on the platform today, the more effort it will be to move away from it.

Alternately, you may opt for some other PaaS-y offering that's built on VMSS. It may be worth checking out offerings like App Services, AKS, or Service Fabric to see whether they'll meet your needs. :)